# How can I parse this text format with PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, text-processing

How can I parse this data with PHP? I don't recognise the format. The field name seems to be formed with `[a-z]` and `_`. Sub-fields should be indented with 2 spaces.

```
---
field_name:
  sub_field: This is text content
  sub_field1: |-
    This is multiline text content. This is multiline text content. This is multiline text content.

    This is multiline text content.

    Thanks
  number_field: 2
  another_field: ''
  array_field: []
field_name1:
  sub_field_with_empty_value: 
  note: single line text field can have serveral lines
this is also 'note' field

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Examples) file. See the [PHP YAML parsing reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse.php).